# Why am I getting these two errors while trying to create a string array?

Tags: java

```
String[] wordArray = { “aardvark”, “bat”, “brewers”, “cadmium”, “wolf”, “dastardly”, “enigmatic”, “frenetic”, “sycophant”, “rattle”, “zinc”, “alloy”, “tunnel”, “nitrate”, “sample”, “yellow”, “mauve”, “abbey”, “thinker”, “junk"};
```

I'm getting the errors:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - String literal is not properly closed by a 
     double-quote
```

Comment: Those look like smart quotes and not standard quotes.

Comment: Like @BoristheSpider said, Java is using `"`, not `“..”` pair to create String literals.

Comment: Remember to not copy code from websites that do this. (Oh and make sure your keyboard is not sending out mono spaced characters) Anyways two errors because `“` is not a valid symbol, and `aardvark` isn't surrounded by standard quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use standard double quote `""` like:

```
  String[] wordArray = { "aardvark", "bat", "brewers",...
```

Answer (score 0):

*That is common problem when you are copying code from documents or websites.*

In Java we are creating String literals by starting end ending them with `"` character, but many document editors are using `“` and `”` to create quotes, which are not recognized as proper start-end of string marks.

You can try to generate proper code with this helper method:

```
public static String fixQuotes(String text){
    return text.replaceAll("“|”", "\""); //replace “ OR ” with " (we need to escape `"` 
                                         //with \ to make compiler treat " as literal and 
                                         //not end of string
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(fixQuotes("String[] wordArray = { “aardvark”, “bat”, “brewers”, “cadmium”, “wolf”, “dastardly”, “enigmatic”, “frenetic”, “sycophant”, “rattle”, “zinc”, “alloy”, “tunnel”, “nitrate”, “sample”, “yellow”, “mauve”, “abbey”, “thinker”, “junk\"};"));
```

Which will print code which you can use later.

```
String[] wordArray = { "aardvark", "bat", "brewers", "cadmium", "wolf", "dastardly", "enigmatic", "frenetic", "sycophant", "rattle", "zinc", "alloy", "tunnel", "nitrate", "sample", "yellow", "mauve", "abbey", "thinker", "junk"};
```

But be careful since this method will replace all `“` or `”` with `"`, not just those which you intend to be start and end of string.